# Symfony as symlink on another server

Tags: php, apache, symfony, symlink, rhel

I would like to make a symfony project that i created on a webserver 
available on another server by the use of symlinks.

I've already set up nfs between the 2 servers and created a symlink to the web folder of symfony, however i always get a blank page when calling the desired webpage. 
the apache error log doesn't make me wiser in any way .

"PHP Fatal error:  Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0"

now since the database the symfony connects to resides on the other server aswell, i think that will be the cause ,however i'm not certain.

anyone got an idea how to fix this?or how to debug it to make it easier because exception thrown without a stack frame seems a bit too general ...

Comment: To me that's not likely to be a database problem, messages are usually a lot more specific. Not a symfony error either, as if the framework boots, you get a stack trace instead of a blank page. It's more likely to be an Apache, php-fpm or network configuration problem.

Comment: Julien is right. Have you checked the `FollowSymlinks` Apache directive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it using the Alias directive(pointing it to the source directory of the first server) of apache rather then a symbolic link, since followsymlinks didn't fix my problem.